# SWT get default font from browser

Tags: java, fonts, swt

How I can get the default browser font depending on current OS from `org.eclipse.swt.browser.Browser`?

For example on Windows, the browser uses "Times New Roman".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default font that is used depends on the rendering engine (IE, Mozilla, Webkit) that is currently used by the Browser widget.

Since `Browser#getFont()` does not reflect this, you can only work around this limitation. A possible approach would be to let the browser execute Javascript code that returns the font of the body tag like so:

```
Browser browser = new Browser( shell, SWT.NONE );
browser.setText( "<html><head></head><body></body></html>" );
browser.addProgressListener( new ProgressAdapter() {
  public void completed( ProgressEvent event ) {
    Object font = browser.evaluate( "return document.defaultView.getComputedStyle( document.body, null ).getPropertyValue('font-family');" );
  }
} );
```

This returns at least on my (Windows) system the actual font used by the browser engine.